# 500 Internal Server Error coming when large amount of data is POST to a php file around more than 1 mb 

Tags: php, error-handling, internal

Can anyone explain me why 500 Internal Server Error coming when large amount of data is POST to a php file and the data is around more than 1 mb?

Comment: 500 status is showing..whihc means internal server error.

Comment: Yes, and whenever there is an internal server error, there will be a line in the `error.log` file telling you what exactly happened. Do you have access to that file?

Comment: Do you upload a file or text data? Maybe php has not enough memory to allocate... try something like @ini_set("memory_limit",'32M');

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that the file is exceeding your configured maximum file size. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php for various discussion and solutions for throwing a prettier error message.

As to increasing those limits, look at "post_max_size" and "upload_max_size" in your .ini file. You'll also likely need to extend the execution time of the script, via "max_input_time" and "max_execution_time".

You can set these in your .ini, or in code as well. See http://blogs.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/ for more info.

Comment: We have already did this in our php.ini but still no result from the same any other cause of this..

Comment: Ok, more info needed. Host OS? (Win/Linux/etc.) Web Server? (IIS, Apache, etc.) PHP Version? Are you hosting on your own servers or with a hosting company? What errors are you logging? (Try setting error_reporting (E_ALL) at the beginning of your code.)

Comment: OS-windows,Web server-abyss,php version-5.2.10 the site is launched with some hosting company,it always show us the 500 error when we are posting that much amount of data.

Comment: Are you taking the data and then dropping it into MySQL? Or is the data going to live on the file system?

Comment: Ok i tell you the whole scenario we are sending a request from our delphi code to php with the data in the post form,but that posted data sometime working fine but sometime it is sowng in the logs that 500 status error.